# Filter list based on KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list that i would like to filter based on a List of KeyValuePairs. All the keys in the KeyValuePair exist in the object.

So let's say i have a list of objects from this class:

```
public class filters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a KeyValuePair with:

```
Key: "Name", Value: "test"
Key: "Country", Value: "SE"
```

Is it possible to generate some kind of LINQ predicate from the KeyValuePair that is usable as `list.Where(predicate)`, and the predicate would be the same as if I would have written `list.Where(c => c.Name == "test" && c.Country == "SE")` ?

Or how should I approach this?

Comment: Have you tried reflection?

Comment: Not sure how i would use reflection for this

Comment: `var keySet = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Name", "test" } };
            Predicate<filters> condition = (c) => c.Name == keySet["Name"] && c.Country == keySet["Country"]; list.Where(condition);` Is this what you are interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"Name", "test"}, {"Country", "SE"}};
var result = list.Where(item => filters.All(f => (string)(item.GetType().GetProperty(f.Key)?.GetValue(item)) == f.Value));
```

This enables you to have an unlimited number of filters.

For each `item` in your `list` the `All` predicate will check the validity for each filter. `item.GetType()` gets the `Type` (ie information about your class) for your `item`. `GetProperty(f.Key)` gets information for the specific property, named by the `Key` of the current filter `f`. `GetValue(item)` gets the value of the property for the current `item`. The `?` is a new feature of c# 6, ie it's an inline check for `null`, ie if the property is not found, it does not try to execute `GetValue` -- which would raise a `NullReferenceException` -- but returns `null`. You then have to cast the property value to `string` and compare it to the `Value` of the current filter. You can also use String::Compare (or any other comparison method you prefer).

`All` only returns `true` if all filters are met and false otherwise. So the result of this query will contain all elements which meet all the filters in your Dictionary

Comment: Please note that using this approach will not perform very well with large lists. Out of curiosity I have compared this solution with the one I suggested (which uses compiled expressions) and to filter a list with one million entries using three filters this approach takes **~400 ms** while my approach takes **~30 ms**. However, for small lists this solution will work better (since building the compiled expression takes some time).

Comment: @fknx  Yes, of course such an on-the-fly approach does not scale as well as a precompiled predicate. Which one to prefer depends on the specific use case.  This was just to show, that it is possible to solve the problem with a one-liner,

Answer (score 0):

I might have mis understood you here but does this do what you want:

```
// say I have a list of ilters like this 
// assume there are actually some filters in here though
var filterCollection = new List<filters>() 

// build dictionary of key values
var keyedSet = filterCollection.ToDictionary(i => i.Name + i.Country, i => i);

// query them using key ...
var filterItem = keyedSet["testSE"];
```

... or you can wrap the predicate in an extension method ...

```
public IEnumerable<filters> ByNameAndCountry(this IEnumerable<filters> collection, string name, string country)
{
     return collection.Where(i => i.Name == name && i => i.Country == country);
}
```

... having done that you can filter the original list like this ...

```
var result = filterCollection.ByNameAndCountry("test", "ES");
```

Comment: I don't want to have to write i => i.Name + i.Country, this should be generated by my KeyValuePair. However i know i can't simply use a string-value to get the field in a lambda, like c => c.StringValue == StringValue

Comment: Hmmm ... so you want to wrap the predicate in an extension method? ... does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Getting the Propertyname through reflection and do an equality check.

```
Func<filters, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, bool> filter = (filters, pairs) =>
{
    foreach (var valuePair in pairs)
    {
        if (filters.GetType().GetProperty(valuePair.Key).GetValue(filters) != valuePair.Value)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

List<filters> list = new List<filters>();
list.Add(new filters() { Name = "Name1", Country = "DE"});
list.Add(new filters() { Name = "Name2", Country = "SE"});

var element = list.FirstOrDefault(x => filter(x, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "Name2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Country", "SE"),
}));

Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Filter> filters = new List<Filter>() {
        new Filter {Name = "Filter1", Age = 1, Country ="De"},
        new Filter {Name = "Filter2", Age = 2, Country ="Fr"},
        new Filter {Name = "Filter3", Age = 3, Country ="It"},
        new Filter {Name = "Filter4", Age = 4, Country ="Es"},
    };

    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Filter1", "De");

    var result = filters.AsQueryable().Where (GetPredicate(kvp));
    result.Dump();
}
//Create the predicate as an expression, which takes a Filter as input and a kvp as a parameter
private static Expression<Func<Filter, bool>> GetPredicate(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp)
{
        return (f) => f.Name == kvp.Key && f.Country == kvp.Value;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want a `Predicate<filters>` generated from KeyValuePair, which is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. So it's

```
Func<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, Predicate<filters>>
```

Use reflection to enumerate `All` properties listed in KeyValuePair.Key and check if each property value match KeyValuePair.Value. Full code is like

```
var lists = new List<filters> { new filters { Name = "abc", Country = "def" } };

Func<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>, Predicate<filters>> predicateBuilder =
( keyValueParis ) => filter => ( from kp in keyValueParis
                                 let pi = typeof( filters ).GetProperty( kp.Key )
                                 select pi.GetValue( filter ) == kp.Value )
                              .All( r => r );

var predicates = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", "abc" ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Country", "def")
};
Predicate<filters> predicate = predicateBuilder( predicates );

Console.WriteLine( lists.FindAll(predicate).Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var keyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair>
    {
        new KeyValuePair {Key = "Name", Value = "Test"},
        new KeyValuePair {Key = "Age", Value = "42"},
        new KeyValuePair {Key = "Country", Value = "USA"}
    };

    var list = new List<Filter>();
    list.Add(new Filter { Name = "Test", Age = "42", Country = "USA" });

    list.Where(keyValuePairs.ToPredicate<Filter>()).Dump();
}

public class Filter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class KeyValuePair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public static class KeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static Func<T, bool> ToPredicate<T>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> keyValuePairs)
    {
        if (keyValuePairs == null || !keyValuePairs.Any())
            return t => false; // default value in case the enumerable is empty

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var equalExpressions = new List<BinaryExpression>();

        foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(keyValuePair.Key);

            var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);

            var value = Expression.Constant(keyValuePair.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType);

            var equalExpression = Expression.Equal(property, value);
            equalExpressions.Add(equalExpression);
        }

        var expression = equalExpressions.First();

        if (equalExpressions.Count > 1)
        {
            // combine expression with and
            expression = Expression.AndAlso(equalExpressions[0], equalExpressions[1]);

            for (var i = 2; i < equalExpressions.Count; i++)
            {
                expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, equalExpressions[i]);
            }
        }

        var lambda = (Func<T, bool>)Expression.Lambda(expression, parameter).Compile();
        return lambda;
    }
}
```

You could also extend the `ToPredicate` method to combine the `KeyValuePairs` with something else than `and`.