# C# - building dynamic lambda expressions

Tags: c#

Have a lambda expression that changes like this:

```
p => p.sourceid
p => p.targetid
p => p.someothervalue1
p => p.someothervalue2
etc.
```

To avoid writing a lot of duplicate code, I would like to make a function that builds the lambdas dynamically based on a string value (`sourceid`, `targetid`, etc.)

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: So are those lambda arrows `=>` converted into simple delegates `Func<,>`, or are they converted into expression trees `Expression<Func<,>>`?

Comment: So in essence you want to replace compile-time checked and Intellisense-supported names with magic strings? I usually strive or recommend to achieve the opposite, which is to abolish, avoid or reduce magic strings. Also you'd lose capabilities offered by VS such as Refactoring and Find All References.

Comment: This question is by far to broad for Stack. Show what you´ve tried already.

Comment: You could build your own [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) and then compile it to create your lambda dynamically. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37029041/5751142) might help you to get you started.

Comment: I found an simple answer to build lambda expression to access field https://rogeralsing.com/2008/02/26/linq-expressions-access-private-fields/

Comment: I agree with @PeterB, Also, how would whatever solution remove the "duplication of code" you want to avoid? instead of writing `p=>p.Something` n times, you will end writing `myVerySpecialSolution("something")` n times.